# TensorFlow: Are saved variables from tf.saved_model and tf.train.Saver not compatible?

Tags: tensorflow

I saved a TensorFlow model using `tf.saved_model` and now I'm trying to load only the variables from that model using a `tf.train.Saver`, but I get one of the following two errors depending on the path I give it:

```
DataLossError: Unable to open table file saved_model/variables:
Failed precondition: saved_model/variables: perhaps your file is in a
different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
```

or

```
InvalidArgumentError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor:
Failed to get matching files on saved_model/variables/variables:
Not found: saved_model/variables
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2_34 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT],
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]
(_arg_save/Const_1_0_0,
save/RestoreV2_34/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_34/shape_and_slices)]]
```

`tf.saved_model`, when saving a model, creates a `saved_model.pb` protocol buffer and a folder named `variables` that contains two files:

1. `variables.data-00000-of-00001`
2. `variables.index`

`tf.train.Saver.save()` creates the following files:

1. `some_name.data-00000-of-00001`
2. `some_name.index`
3. `some_name.meta`
4. `checkpoint`

I have always assumed that the two output files ending in `.data-00000-of-00001` and `.index` are compatible between both savers.

Is that not the case?

Comment: You could extract the checkpoint from the saved model (which has a metagraph and a checkpoint), but does [saved_model.loader](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/loader) work for you?

Comment: @AllenLavoie I can load the model with `saved_model.loader`, but I want to load the variables only, not the metagraph. I have a slightly different graph that I want to load the variables into. What I did as a work-around is to load the model with `saved_model.loader`, then add a `tf.train.Saver` and use that to save the variables, and then restore them into the new graph with `tf.train.Saver`. I just thought that the variables checkpoint that `SavedModel` creates would (and should) be compatible with the one `tf.train.Saver` creates, but that doesn't seem to be the case.